# getting blank page after submiting form PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am currenlty making a forum website for my uni assignment and trying to insert topics into a subcategory. It keeps bring me to a blank page after pressing submit. the url is http://localhost:8000/addnewtopic.php?cid=1&scid=1 for the blank page, it also doesnt end up importing the data into my database

```html
 <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
            {
                echo "<form action='/addnewtopic.php?cid=".$_GET['cid']."&scid=".$_GET['scid']."' method='POST'>
                <p>Title: </p>
                <input type='text' id='topic' name='topic' size='100' />
                <p>Content: </p>
                <textarea id='content' name='content'></textarea><br />
                <input type='submit' value='add new post' /><form>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>Please login first or <a href='register.html'>click here</a> to register.</p>";
            }
        ?>
```

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    include('db_connection.php');

    $topic = addslashes($_POST['topic']);
    $content = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['content']));
    $cid = $_GET['cid'];
    $scid = $_GET['scid'];

    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO topics (category_id, subcategory_id, author, title, content, date_posted) 
                  VALUES ('".$cid."', '".$scid."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$topic."', '".$content."', NOW());");

    if ($insert)
    {
        header("Location: topics.php?cid=".$cid."&scid=".$scid."");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you start the session before checking the session variable?

Comment: yeah i have just double checked to make sure. The session start is in my code to check the user has logged in

Comment: Does the inspect tool shows any element at all including the form?

Comment: you mean like the text box for the title of the topic and the other text box for the content along with the submit button? cause that shows when i inspect the page under the specific category and subcategory

Comment: Hmm that's weird. If all of the elements are there, the form isn't empty then

Comment: [Error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out. it was with my SQL statment